# How to show an error message inside JDesktop pane on top of internalframe

Tags: java, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

i want to display error massages inside the jdesktop pane in java
i have not done anything yet and am a beginner sorry for the broken English

i tried using JDialog but comes up on top of everything thisnthe code am using to call the JDialog

```
private  boolean showAdmin_T() {
        admin_priv obj = new admin_priv(fram, true);
        fram.getRootPane().getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        obj.showMessage();
        return obj.isOk();
    }
```

i created a separate JDialog but it only opens outside the JDesktop pane
here is the code for the Jdialog

```
package com.mutale.posapplication.dialogs;

import com.mutale.posapplication.scroll.ScrollBarCustom;
import com.mutale.posapplication.swing.icons.GoogleMaterialDesignIcons;
import com.mutale.posapplication.swing.icons.IconFontSwing;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.Animator;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTarget;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTargetAdapter;
public class error_disply extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    private String icon; 
    public boolean isOk() {
        return ok;
    }
    public void setOk(boolean ok) {
        this.ok = ok;
    }
    private boolean ok;
    private final Animator animator;
    private boolean show = true;
    public error_disply(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal,String icon1) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        icon = "1";
        panel(error_ScrollPane);
        lbMessage.setLineWrap(true);
        lbMessage.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setOpacity(0f);
        if(icon.equals(icon1)){      lbIcon.setIcon(IconFontSwing.buildIcon(GoogleMaterialDesignIcons.STORAGE, 60, new Color(254, 86, 96), new Color(113, 74, 67)));
        }else{
            lbIcon.setIcon(IconFontSwing.buildIcon(GoogleMaterialDesignIcons.REPORT_PROBLEM, 40, new Color(254, 86, 96), new Color(113, 74, 67)));
        }
       getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       TimingTarget target = new TimingTargetAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void timingEvent(float fraction) {
                if (show) {
                    setOpacity(fraction);
                } else {
                    setOpacity(1f - fraction);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void end() {
                if (show == false) {
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        };
        animator = new Animator(200, target);
        animator.setResolution(0);
        animator.setAcceleration(0.5f);
    }
    public void showMessage(String message) {
        lbMessage.setText(message);
        animator.start();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public final void panel(JScrollPane scroll) {
        scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new ScrollBarCustom());
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scroll.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, p);
        scroll.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lbIcon = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cancele = new com.mutale.posapplication.swings.Button();
        error_ScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        lbMessage = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0), 2));    lbIcon.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        cancele.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(202, 5, 5));
        cancele.setText("X");
        cancele.setToolTipText("close");
        cancele.setColorGradient(new java.awt.Color(202, 5, 5));
        cancele.setEnabled(false);
        cancele.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        cancele.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                canceleMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        lbMessage.setEditable(false);
        lbMessage.setColumns(3);
        lbMessage.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        lbMessage.setRows(4);
        lbMessage.setAutoscrolls(false);
        lbMessage.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        error_ScrollPane.setViewportView(lbMessage);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(lbIcon, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(cancele, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addComponent(error_ScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 540, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(cancele, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lbIcon, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(error_ScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 331, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );    cancele.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(cancele);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(      layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(       layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>    
    private void canceleMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        ok = true;
        closeMenu();
    }
    private void closeMenu() {
        if (animator.isRunning()) {
            animator.stop();
        }
        show = false;
        animator.start();
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private com.mutale.posapplication.swings.Button cancele;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane error_ScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbIcon;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea lbMessage;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mre] that illustrates your problem.  We can copy your code into our IDE, compile, run, and test it.  You can add an error message `JLabel` to a `JPanel`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: check the update one  -Gilbert Le Blanc